# Valgrind and Deallocating Special Array of Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, valgrind

I have a hash table storage implementation with stores a typedef struct of Entry, and there is a function that queries the entire table to see if the entry's data matches a specific set of conditions. The way I implemented this is the server utilizes

`Entry **queryReturns = tableQuery(params);`

in order to call the function, and the function allocates memory for an array of Entry pointers to return.

(In the tableQuery function:)

```
Entry **tableQuery(params) {
    //Process params and get expected results
    Entry **returnEntries = (Entry *)malloc(j * sizeof(Entry *));
    //Code to copy pointers into the array
    return returnEntries;
}
```

When the server function is done with this, I should only deallocate this with

```
free(queryReturns);
```

Since I don't want to delete the actual data elements that I'm storing, I only want to deallocate this temporary array of Entry pointers, but Valgrind produces this message:

```
205,816 bytes in 96 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 17 of 17
    at 0x4C28BED: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:263)
    by 0x4086D1: tableQuery (Table.c:798)
    by 0x403808: handle_command (server.c:645)
    by 0x403F05: threadCall (server.c:799)
    by 0x52B3B4F: start_thread (pthread_create.c:304)
```

Should I worry about this causing memory leaks, or should I just ignore this?

Comment: Look at `tableQuery()` code or documentation and check how to free memory allocated by it.

Comment: "*//Code to copy pointers into the array*" which pointers?

Comment: tableQuery is my own function that I created. The pointers are referring to pointers to the data elements that match the query. The function returns an array of these so the server can directly access the data elements.

Comment: that cast. shouldn't that be `(Entry **)malloc( ...`?

Comment: No, actually there should not be a cast

Comment: Probably there are no pointers left to some of the actual data elements. We don't see the rest of the code handling those data elements, so I think we can't help you.

Comment: What do you mean by no pointers left? I've run the rest of the code without any Valgrind issues before, it was only after I added the tableQuery function that this occurs, so it should be isolated to this.

Comment: I've looked at some other solutions, would declaring an Entry *returnEntries[j] work, or would that be destroyed at the end of the function?

Comment: Do you ever allocate other memory and perhaps assign it to `Entry[i]` ?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I worry about this causing memory leaks

Yes: this is a definite memory leak, and you *should* worry about it.

Unfortunately, you didn't tell us whether this line:

```
Entry **returnEntries = (Entry *)malloc(j * sizeof(Entry *));
```

is the allocation line (`Table.c:798`) that Valgrind complains about.

If it is, then at least one of callers of `tableQuery()` is not in fact `free`ing the returned array like it should.